# I want to migrate a site from joomla to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, joomla

Is there a way to migrate one JOOMLA site to WORDPRESS from a different server to another without having access to joomla's cpanel??

Or is there a way to find the joomla's database password without makeing any changes to the site, in order to use a plugin?

Comment: are you trying to hack some ones code??

Comment: lol of course not. I just dont know about joomla and i try to find where the database is stored without changing it just to get the password for a plugin i found.